# AJAX отправка файла на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xhr

Здравствуйте как можно отправить частями файл на сервер.

Как отправить просто файл, например так:

```js
let xhr = _self.getXmlHttp();
xhr.open('post', "example.php");
let formData = new FormData(document.forms[0].files[0]);
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
xhr.send(formData);
```

На сервере он попадет в глобальную пересменную `PHP: $_FILES`.

Как можно можно оправить файл на сервер, с возможностью приостановки загрузки?
И можно ли отправить файл как то иначе чем через форму, например с заголовками: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` или `application/octet-stream`, и как его поместить в `$_FILES`?

Comment: зачем отправлять файл частями?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Если он большой, что бы разбить, отправлять частями и была возможность приостановить, вполне возможно я не прав и при приостановка происходит без разбиения файла

Comment: смотря какой файл, ну вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121917/split-an-uploaded-file-into-multiple-chunks-using-javascript

Comment: @Jean-Claude Вообще да, оно, а файл длинный видос. А можно ли его в base64 и отправить с заголовком octet/stream,  как в этом случае разрезать представляю, но как на сервере собрать

Comment: а я не представляю как яваскриптом файл резать))

Comment: @Jean-Claude так не буду себя топить, в своей глупости, лучше соберу из скинутового вами ответа, там думаю то, что надо))